# Get field machine name inside HOOK_preprocess_file_link()?

Tags: 8, hooks

I am hoping to get the field name inside `hook_preprocess_file_link()`.

I only want to alter the link of the file for certain field names.

`hook_preprocess_field()` would probably work, but I would prefer to use `hook_preprocess_file_link()`.

Is it possible to get the field name in this hook?

#### mymodule.module

```php
function mymodule_preprocess_file_link(&$variables, $fieldName) {
  // This returns "file_link" instead of the field name like "field_myfilefield".
  kpr($fieldName);
}

function mymodule_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['field_name'])) {
    $fieldName = $variables['field_name'];
  }

  mymodule_preprocess_file_link($variables, $fieldName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the field name to the file link through `hook_preprocess_field()`
A similar approach is used in [Themable Forms](https://www.drupal.org/project/themable_forms) module.
Check its [module](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/themable_forms/blob/8.x-1.x/themable_forms.module) file.

Comment: Is that possible between two preprocess functions?

Comment: I tried it with form and form elements. Did you try to implement it?

Comment: Updated my question with some more code I've tried.